# Concession speeches

Tags: united-states, election

If a Presidential candidate loses the election, and then loses a failed recount effort, is it customary for her to have to give a second Concession speech?

Comment: I don't think so, the recount effort wasn't even started by the candidate in the first place (if you are referring to 2016). Technically, it's the same for the victory speech, the winning candidate don't give another speech to celebrate the failed recount effort

Comment: @Panda - in 2016, it'd not bet against the latter either :)  At least a Twitter speech :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is customary in terms of concession speeches. Both Mitt Romney and John McCain delivered their concession speeches right after calling Barack Obama to congratulate him. However, Hillary Clinton made her speech much later at [10:30 am EST on Nov. 9, 2016](http://time.com/4564143/hillary-clinton-concession-speech/). It took far longer for Al Gore and he made it on [Dec. 13, 2000](http://www.authentichistory.com/1993-2000/3-2000election/3-dispute/20001213_VP_Gore_Concession.html) after the Supreme Court decision and Dec. 12th deadline for recount in Florida.

Based on the above examples, we can safely assume that it is not customary for any candidate to give a concession speech on a specific date or event.

Answer (score 0):

> If a Presidential candidate loses the election, and then loses a failed recount effort, is it customary for her to have to give a second Concession speech?

#### No.

It's a courtesy for the loser to give a concession speech in order to unite the country, it isn't a requirement by law.

Since it's already clear that the presidential candidate already lost the election and gave a concession speech, there's no point in giving another one for losing the recount effort.

The recount effort isn't thought to change the results in the first place. So, unless it changes the outcome, it's isn't customary to give another speech.

Comment: I asked what was customary, not what is legal.